# TMENU - only mark current page as active, not parents

Tags: typo3

I have a menu currently looking like this. Not only the current active item is marked as active, but also its parents and all the way up. How can I make it so parents aren't marked?

[image]

Here's the menu typoscript.

```
lib.secondNavi = HMENU
lib.secondNavi.entryLevel=0
lib.secondNavi.1 = TMENU
lib.secondNavi.1 {
    wrap = <ul id="secondNavi">|</ul>
    expAll = 0
    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    RO < .NO
    RO = 1
    CUR < .NO
    CUR = 1
    CUR.allWrap = <li class="active">|</li>
    ACT < .CUR
}

lib.secondNavi.2 < lib.secondNavi.1
lib.secondNavi.2 {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
}

lib.secondNavi.3 < lib.secondNavi.2
lib.secondNavi.3 {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
}
```

Using Typo3 6.1.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active (ACT) in TypoScript means current page AND each parent in the page tree.

Current page (CUR) is only the page that you are on (determined by its ID)

[**documentation**](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/CommonItemStates/Index.html)

You are copying settings of `CUR` to `ACT` so you have mark the pages on rootline as well, just remove the `ACT < .CUR` line or on other levels empty it by: `ACT >`

Comment: Thanks. Still wrapping my head around typoscript, and this helps a lot.

Comment: Head up, with time it becomes more familiar, just matter of practice :)